# IPFW Port Forwarding

Tags: osx, firewall, openvpn, port-forwarding, ipfw

This is my situation: I want to connect to an OpenVPN server from my office (we're using a proxy, only ports 80 and 443 are allowed).

Server IP address is: 176.31.250.232:843

My static IP address is: 192.168.78.241

Is possibile to forward the 843 TCP port to the 443 port using IPFW? (I'm on OSX).

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: if you are behind a proxy, you have to involve the proxy in your project. maybe this way for openvpn: [openvpn via proxy](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#http)

Answer (score 0):

If the office proxy only allows outgoing connections to ports 80 and 443 and that can't be changed, you need a forwarder in the internet (outside the office intranet, behind its proxy).

Simplest would be to change the server to listen on port 443 instead or on both 843 and 443. The latter could be achieved by adding a port forwarding rule on the server itself.

If you can't change the proxy or the server, a forwarding rule on any internet server you have access to would do the job. That would be no security problem since it just handles encrypted data. The only drawback is traffic on the forwarding server and maybe its limiting bandwidth.